# Redux action property defaulting to 'undefined' rather than an empty array

Tags: arrays, redux

I have noticed that when setting and initial state action object in redux, that empty arrays return `undefined`, which is keeping me from accessing array methods like `.push()` or `.length`.

Is there a way to stop the value from simplifying down to undefined?

```
export const startAddCustomer = (customerData = {}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const {
            name = '',
            age = 0,
            address = {
                address: '',
                city: '',
                state: ''
            },
            coats = [],
            shoes = [],
            phoneNumber = '',
            dependants = [],
            visits = [],
        } = customerData;
        const customer = {
            name,
            age,
            address,
            coats,
            shoes,
            phoneNumber,
            dependants,
            visits
        };

        database.ref('customers').push(customer).then((ref) => {
            dispatch(addCustomer({
                id: ref.key,
                ...customer
            }))
        })

    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which part of your example is returning the `undefined`?

Comment: I figured out that this was a firebase issue rather than a redux issue. When saving to firebase, values such as an empty array are interpreted as undefined, therefore not being saved to the database. I solved this by saving empty values as 'false', then constructing a new array when I needed to store something in that key.

Comment: Great! Glad you worked it out.